# mysql: insert operation errors "data too long "

Tags: mysql

in mysql, create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE fb_group_feed (
    Post_ID varchar(64), 
    Permalink varchar(128), 
    Create_time varchar(32), 
    Updated_time varchar(32), 
    Author varchar(32),
    Author_ID bigint, 
    Message text, 
    Link varchar(1024), 
    Likes int, 
    Comments int, 
    group_ID bigint, 
    foreign key(group_ID) references fb_group_info(ID)
)
```

when insert a line of data in this table, there is error:

```
INSERT INTO fb_group_feed VALUES (
    '1610393525875114_1842755835972214','https://www.facebook.com/groups/1610393525875114/permalink/1842755835972214/',
    '2017-01-22T17:12:41+0000','2017-01-23T00:45:16+0000','Chibura Hakkai',457297014658600,
    'Pretty hands he has... credit Wilma Alberti',
    'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=466756323712669&set=gm.1842755835972214&type=3',   
    175,7,1610393525875114)
```

it errors:

```
 Error 1406(22001): "Data too long for column 'Post_ID' at row 1")
```

but I have set 'Post_ID' varchar(64), i think it is long enough.Could you please help for that

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/345eb Are you sure the columns are in the order that you show?

Answer (score 0):

*First* thing you should do is a `describe fb_group_feed`, that will tell you the current order of the columns, which is the order used for insertions if you don't specify those columns explicitly. As per the [doco](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> If you do not specify a list of column names for `INSERT ... VALUES` or `INSERT ... SELECT`, values for every column in the table must be provided by the `VALUES` list or the `SELECT` statement. If you do not know the order of the columns in the table, use `DESCRIBE tbl_name` to find out.

Alternatively (and far safer) would be to use the *explicit* form:

```
INSERT INTO fb_group_feed (
    Post_ID, 
    Permalink,
    <other columns>
) VALUES (
    '1610393525875114_1842755835972214',
    'https://www.facebook.com/groups/blah/blah/blah/',
    <other values>
)
```

Comment: He showed the `CREATE TABLE` query that was used. The columns are always in the same order as specified there.

Comment: @Barmar, there may well have been changes to the table after creation, or the statement may have been wrong/misremembered, or he might have failed creating a new table when the old one still existed (with possibly less than the needed space). Bottom line is that the data seemingly being inserted should fit yet MySQL complains. My advice still stands, `describe table` is the definitive way to figure out what a "naked" insert will do, and you shouldn't be using naked inserts at all, for portability.